# load next offer when answer has been submitted

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm trying to build a simple offer survey app (PHP  using Fuel Framework).

I want to serve one question at a time.
A user then has to answer Save or Bin.
Only when they have answered do I want to serve the next question.

What's the best way of doing this? Currently all questions stored in the DB are displayed on a page.

Matt

Comment: Just display one question at a time? (and only if previously are marked as answered, except the first)

Comment: where's your code, what have you tried, what errors are you getting?

Comment: this is the offer page - http://pastebin.com/GeSPGLk4 & this is the offer template http://pastebin.com/F6rnV4gF

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it in PHP where each question is a form that is submitted to the server and then the user is given the next question or you can do it with Javascript so that the form contains all the questions, but is hidden from view. Answering a question reveals the next question.

Advantages of PHP Method:

1) It would be easier to save progress
2) Each question can be validated one at a time
3) Greater number of people can take the survey (people without javascript)

Advantages of Javascript:

1) It would be smoother and more elegant
2) The entire form is served at once and is revealed as needed
3) Reduced number of page requests.